# load xelement into a datatable

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

i have the following xml file, that contains a lot of Information about branches of a company ..
(this is only an example)..

what i really need, is to load only the data from Branch1 in a datatable(that has the same structure as my xml file, so no problem with the datatable at all) ..

iam using c# and i would like to do this is linq, but i have no idea about linq...
my question is:
how would i read the entry from xml as a datatable row, so i can copy it to my datatable ?

i now have:

```
XElement main = XElement.Load("branches.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elList =
from el in main.Descendants("branch").Where(ex=>ex.Attribute("name").Value=="Branch1")
select el;
//this will return me the element where name =Branch1
//now, how would i only load this entry into my datatable ??
//this won`t work
branchesDataTable.ReadXml(XElement el in elList);
```

any help is really appreciated ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<branches>
<branch name="Branch1">
    <address>Street 1, 1234, NY</address>
    <tel>0123456789</tel>
    <director>James</director>
</branch>   
<branch name="Branch2">
    <address>Street 2, 4567, NY</address>
    <tel>9876543210</tel>
    <director>Will</director>
</branch>
</branches>
```

Comment: You may be confusing "LINQ" with "LINQ to SQL". You should probably not use LINQ to SQL, but should instead look at Entity Framework.

Comment: hi john...
it has nothing to do with sql, iam just loading my xml contents into a datatable...sorry iam may didnt understand what you mean exactly !?iam programming in C#...thx for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
branchesDataTable.ReadXml(new StringReader(new XElement("branches", elList).ToString()));
```

Comment: iam getting an "Illegal characters in path" Exception

Comment: the (new XElement("branches", elList).ToString()) is putting the whole xml node in another <branch</branch> tag...this means iam getting the following now :
<branch>
<branch name="branch1">
 <address>Street 1, 1234, NY</address>
    <tel>0123456789</tel>
    <director>James</director>
</branch>
</branch>

Comment: hi ...it should be like this after i choose which node i want :<branch name="branch1"> <address>Street 1, 1234, NY</address> <tel>0123456789</tel> <director>James</director> </branch> without the extra opening and ending <branch> tags ...

Comment: @lebhero added StringReader.. see if that helps.

Comment: @lebhero I don't have the datatable with associated schema so I cannot test it. but the rest of the code filters the branches and correctly produces xml.

Comment: my mistake, it works ... i just mistyped the "branches" ..thank you