# How to convert XElement object into a dataset or datatable?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, sharepoint-2007, xelement

I'm accessing a SharePoint(2007) list through a service reference of lists.asmx created in my console application. Console application is created in VS2012 and .Net 4.5 framework.

```
ListsSoapClient proxy1 = new ListsSoapClient();
proxy1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
proxy1.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;    
string listName = "List_For_Test";
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
XElement ndQuery = new XElement("Query", "");
XElement ndViewFields = new XElement("ViewFields", "");
XElement ndQueryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions", "");
XElement items = proxy1.GetListItems(listName, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
ds1 = XElementToDataSet(items);
```

I need to convert the XML returned in items XElement to dataset/datatable and pass it to a stored procedure written in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I tried using following code but it gave me error

```
    XElement setup = (from p in x.Descendants() select p).First();
    foreach (XElement xe in setup.Descendants()) // build your DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(xe.Name.ToString(), typeof(string))); 
    // on second iteration gave error that "'{#RowsetSchema}row'" column already existing.
```

This is the XML stream returned from GetListItems() webservice method call

> `<`listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
>   xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
>   xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> `<`rs:data
>   ItemCount="2"> `<`z:row
>   ows_ContentTypeId="0x01006B57C3DFF39626458A729755ABF3A370"
>   ows_Title="Item#1" ows_ListID="1.00000000000000"
>   ows_Loan_x0020_Number="1234.00000000000" ows_ID="2"
>   ows_ContentType="Item" ows_Modified="2014-04-01 10:06:38"
>   ows_Created="2014-04-01 10:06:38" ows_Author="7017;#, Khushi"
>   ows_Editor="7017;#, Khushi" ows_owshiddenversion="1"
>   ows_WorkflowVersion="1" ows__UIVersion="512"
>   ows__UIVersionString="1.0" ows_Attachments="0"
>   ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="Item#1"
>   ows_LinkTitle="Item#1" ows_SelectTitle="2"
>   ows_Order="200.000000000000"
>   ows_GUID="{2832ED2B-A45D-4950-8E0E-EEB3E31199AF}" ows_FileRef="2;#
>   List_For_Test/2_.000" ows_FileDirRef="2;#/List_For_Test"
>   ows_Last_x0020_Modified="2;#2014-04-01 10:06:38"
>   ows_Created_x0020_Date="2;#2014-04-01 10:06:38" ows_FSObjType="2;#0"
>   ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileLeafRef="2;#2_.000"
>   ows_UniqueId="2;#{F3336392-74F7-45C2-A175-EF36DA219812}"
>   ows_ProgId="2;#"
>   ows_ScopeId="2;#{E9E1B331-7993-4586-93DC-3690EBEBAD9E}"
>   ows__EditMenuTableStart="2_.000" ows__EditMenuTableEnd="2"
>   ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="2_.000" ows_LinkFilename="2_.000"
>   ows_ServerUrl="/ List_For_Test/2_.000"
>   ows_EncodedAbsUrl="Lists/List_For_Test/2_.000" ows_BaseName="2_"
>   ows_MetaInfo="2;#" ows__Level="1" ows__IsCurrentVersion="1" />
>   `<`z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x01006B57C3DFF39626458A729755ABF3A370"
>   ows_Title="Item#2" ows_ListID="2.00000000000000"
>   ows_Loan_x0020_Number="5678.00000000000" ows_ID="3"
>   ows_ContentType="Item" ows_Modified="2014-04-01 10:06:53"
>   ows_Created="2014-04-01 10:06:53" ows_Author="7017;#Khushi"
>   ows_Editor="7017;#, Khushi" ows_owshiddenversion="1"
>   ows_WorkflowVersion="1" ows__UIVersion="512"
>   ows__UIVersionString="1.0" ows_Attachments="0"
>   ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="Item#2"
>   ows_LinkTitle="Item#2" ows_SelectTitle="3"
>   ows_Order="300.000000000000"
>   ows_GUID="{8A6C6A66-A795-4054-B793-789B739EA881}" ows_FileRef="3;#
>   /List_For_Test/3_.000" ows_FileDirRef="3;# /List_For_Test"
>   ows_Last_x0020_Modified="3;#2014-04-01 10:06:53"
>   ows_Created_x0020_Date="3;#2014-04-01 10:06:53" ows_FSObjType="3;#0"
>   ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileLeafRef="3;#3_.000"
>   ows_UniqueId="3;#{434E5737-5591-4A02-91E5-B2C7A2EFF2B3}"
>   ows_ProgId="3;#"
>   ows_ScopeId="3;#{E9E1B331-7993-4586-93DC-3690EBEBAD9E}"
>   ows__EditMenuTableStart="3_.000" ows__EditMenuTableEnd="3"
>   ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="3_.000" ows_LinkFilename="3_.000"
>   ows_ServerUrl="/List_For_Test/3_.000"
>   ows_EncodedAbsUrl="Lists/List_For_Test/3_.000" ows_BaseName="3_"
>   ows_MetaInfo="3;#" ows__Level="1" ows__IsCurrentVersion="1" />
>   `<`/rs:data>   `<`/listitems>

Comment: How do you plan on passing a dataset/datatable to a stored procedure?

Comment: I'll be using SqlCommand object and `cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", dtDetails);` where "@Details" is input parameter name in stored procedure and dtDetails is table name created at C# side.

Comment: A simpler solution is provided here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602581/load-xelement-into-a-datatable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602581/load-xelement-into-a-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Please check it [here...](https://forums.asp.net/t/1379399.aspx?linq%20xml%20to%20Datatable)

```
public static class XElementExtensions {
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this XElement element) {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string rawXml = element.ToString();
    ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(rawXml));
    return ds.Tables[0];
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<XElement> elements) {
    return ToDataTable(new XElement("Root", elements));
}
}
```

Use it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
string xmlFile = Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml");
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var booksQuery = from b in document.Elements("NewDataSet").Elements("Table")
                  select b;

DataTable table = booksQuery.ToDataTable();
GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

khushi,check this may be useful to you....

```
public static DataSet XElementToDataSet(XElement xeRecordsList)
{
  DataTable dtRecordsList = new DataTable();

  XElement setup = (from p in xeRecordsList.Descendants() select p).First();
  // builds DataTable
 foreach (XElement xe in setup.Descendants())
 dtRecordsList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(xe.Name.ToString(), typeof(string)));
 // add columns to your dt

var all = from p in xeRecordsList.Descendants(setup.Name.ToString()) select p;
foreach (XElement xe in all)
{
 DataRow dr = dtRecordsList.NewRow();

 //adding the values
 foreach (XElement xe2 in xe.Descendants())
 {
   bool boolColExists = false;
   //Check for column exists in datatable
   foreach (DataColumn col in dtRecordsList.Columns) 
   {
      if (col.ColumnName == xe2.Name.ToString())
      {
        boolColExists = true;
        break;
      }
   }
  if (boolColExists)
  dr[xe2.Name.ToString()] = xe2.Value;
 }
 dtRecordsList.Rows.Add(dr);
}
DataSet dstRecordsList = new DataSet("RECORDLIST");
dstRecordsList.Tables.Add(dtRecordsList);
dstRecordsList.Tables[0].TableName = "RECORD";
return dstRecordsList;
}
```

some references:
http://www.dotnetpickles.com/2014/02/aspnet-convert-xml-to-datatable-in-cnet.html

Comment: I tried this code and as mentioned in my question, I'm getting 'DuplicateNameException was unhandled' exception with message "A column named '{#RowsetSchema}row' already belongs to this DataTable." on this line of code dtRecordsList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(xe.Name.ToString(), typeof(string))); // add columns to your dt. I edited my question to add the XML generated from webservice method, if that helps.

Comment: can you please provide me sufficient code to check the flow

Comment: I've updated my question and added all proxy code and a call to your method that I'm making after getting results from service. All code is in the `main()` method of a console application.